# Can I safely disable google app on my android as I use chrome app?

Tags: applications

I want to disable google app as I use chrome app.  Is it safe?

Comment: They are different as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.  I haven't even had the Google app installed for most of the time I've had my phone, and I only browse with Chrome.

Note that some ROMs do have a dependency on Google Now, so it's possible that disabling it may cause you other issues.